# ERROR: relation "places" does not exist Heroku db import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I know this kind of error happens when having quotes or case sensitivity error in the query of postgres . Actually i'm having a .sql file which i'm trying to import in my heroku db through command line but constantly having this error .My .sql file contains these queries

```
INSERT INTO "places" ("Name", "Address") VALUES
('Cookshop Restaurant &amp', ' Bar'),
('Cafeteria', '119 7th Ave, New York, NY 10011'),
('Franchia Vegan Cafe', '12 Park Ave, New York, NY 10016');
```

Comment: what error are you getting? Why aren't you using seeds.rb to create data into your app?

Comment: @uDaY relation not exist is the error

Comment: what do you get if you do this? `$ heroku run rake db:version` and after that what do you get if you run this `$ rake db:version` ??

Comment: @uDaY for `heroku` it's `0` while for local it's `20151127134901`

Comment: See my answer and let me know if it worked.!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is heroku doesn't have the migrations that you locally have, in order to have the same db version do the following migration on heroku:

To know the local db version do: `$ rake db:version`

Then take the version you get locally and make sure you have it in heroku by doing the following:

`$ heroku run rake --trace db:migrate VERSION=20151127134901`

**Explanation:** Essentially the above command takes the db migration to heroku with the same version of migration you have locally.

Hope it helps!

Comment: result : Don't know how to build task `'20151127134901'`

Comment: try without a space between = sign and its value.