# Heroku deployment error RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, omniauth

When running my RoR app in Heroku shows this error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Checking the heroku logs, this shows http://pastebin.com/yTWtRMVD

My main page is https://salty-stream-26420.herokuapp.com/ and my callback URL is https://salty-stream-26420.herokuapp.com/auth/twitter/callback in OmniAuth.

It runs in Cloud9 perfectly but not in Heroku. What is wrong?

Thank you, Alex.

Comment: Possibly you have not pushed new db changes to heroku. Try what this answer says http://stackoverflow.com/a/34321825/981616

Comment: I think my db migrate is wrong. This shows http://pastebin.com/R83a3rsN

Comment: So now you know how to fix it? :-/

Comment: @uDaY No, still stuck with the same error. Don't know if it doesn't work because the migration fails or for another reason.

Comment: where is your users table? It doesnt exist? where are you supposed to get that `user_id` from?

Comment: It is weird that your logs are referencing a webrick server.  AFAIK webrick is not supported on Heroku and you need to use Unicorn.

Comment: @ruby_newbie And how do I change this in order to use Unicorn?

Comment: I think you have an error in your migration files.

Comment: Here is a write up on using Puma(sorry not unicorn) rather than Webrick:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
2016-05-03T13:47:23.544506+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "submissions" does not exist
```

suggests to me that you have to simply migrate your database on the remote server.

Try running `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: There might be something amiss or out of order with your migrations. You might be able to diagnose this by starting another dev environment on your machine or a virtual box and trying to set up the database. I reckon you might come across the same error locally if you `rake db:drop` and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create environment variables in the config/database.yml file for the username, password and database name

Those same environment variables need to be defined under

Heroku login >> application >> settings >> reveal config vars

By default you will get a DATABSE_URL something as

```
postgres://wwwbirawxqwmws:7bef28c02299c9c6054a646b5ce19276bbab52feca6692dac8305b32dbd7d36c@ec2-81-XX-XXX-X26.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d6n59y5r09ko99
```

where `wwwbirawxqwmws` is **USER**
and `7bef28c02299c9c6054a646b5ce19276bbab52feca6692dac8305b32dbd7d36c` is **PASSWORD**
and `d6n59y5r09ko99` is the **DATABASE**

These three variables needs to be assigned in the heroku config, then you will be able to run

```
            heroku run rake db:create

            heroku run rake db:migrate
```